# Can a century be undone by a foul?

Tags: snooker

In snooker, if a player achieves a century, but then fouls below 100, does the century still count?

So, for example, suppose a player has a break of 102, but then misses and the cue ball goes into a pocket for -4 so the player's score stands at 98. Is it still considered a century?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because your question is based on a false premise: a foul does not reduce a player's score, but instead increases the opponent's.